# New to time series databases, selecting data from TimescaleDB for Grafana is slow and the query is complex

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, grafana, timescaledb

I'm new to TimescaleDB and Grafana and the query I'm using is slow. I think the query I wrote could be improved a lot but I'm not really sure how. Any advice is appreciated.

I have to following table:

```sql
create table key_value_data (
    "time" timestamptz not null,
    "context" varchar null,
    "key" varchar[] not null,
    "path" varchar not null,
    "value" varchar not null
);

select create_hypertable('key_value_data', 'time');
```

Then I try to select data for a https://github.com/panodata/grafana-map-panel. I tried to explain what I'm trying to achieve in the comments of the query:

```sql
select
    * -- this removes all rows with a null value in one of the columns, see where statement below
from
(
select
    time_bucket_gapfill('5 seconds', "time") as "time", -- create time buckets of 5 seconds
    "name", -- the name of the vessel
    locf(last("lon", "time")) as "lon", -- last reported longitude in this bucket, if unknown in this bucket take the value of the previous bucket
    locf(last("lat", "time")) as "lat", -- last reported latitude in this bucket, if unknown in this bucket take the value of the previous bucket
    locf(last("sog", "time")) as "sog", -- last reported speed over ground in this bucket, if unknown in this bucket take the value of the previous bucket
    locf(last("navstate", "time")) as "navstate" -- last reported navigation state in this bucket, if unknown in this bucket take the value of the previous bucket
from
(
select
     "ais"."time",
    case when "names"."name" is null then "ais"."context" else "names"."name" end as "name",
    max(case when "ais"."path" = 'navigation.position.longitude' then "ais"."value"::numeric else null end) as "lon",
    max(case when "ais"."path" = 'navigation.position.latitude' then "ais"."value"::numeric else null end) as "lat",
    max(case when "ais"."path" = 'navigation.speedOverGround' then "ais"."value"::numeric * 3.6 else null end) as "sog",
    max(case when "ais"."path" = 'navigation.state' then "ais"."value"::varchar else null end) as "navstate"
from
(
select
    "time",
    "context",
    "path",
    "value"
from
    "key_value_data"
where
  $__timeFilter("time") and
    "path" in ('navigation.position.longitude', 'navigation.position.latitude', 'navigation.speedOverGround', 'navigation.state')
order by
    1, 2, 3
) as "ais" -- this is a subquery to pivot the data, I cannot get the crosstab function working because I don't know how to insert the grafana $__timeFilter in the query text
inner join
(
select
    "context",
    last("value", "time") as "name"
from
    "key_value_data" as "names"
where
  $__timeFilter("time") and
    "path" = 'name'
group by 
    1
) as "names" -- I made a separate query to retrieve the name of the vessel because this value is not injected in the table every x seconds but less frequent
on "ais"."context" = "names"."context"
group by
    1, 2
) as "bucket"
where
  $__timeFilter("time")
group by
    1, 2
) as "result"
where
    "lon" is not null and -- remove all rows with a null value in one of these columns
    "lat" is not null and
    "sog" is not null and
    "navstate" is not null
```

The query I ended up with is complex and slow, I think there should be a easier way to do this.

```
Successfully run. Total query runtime: 465 msec.
106233 rows affected.
```

Questions:

1. Is the key value approach a good way to store the data in the key_value_data table? I don't now which keys are available on before hand, it depends on the available sensors on board of a vessel.
2. Is there an easier way to pivot the data that's working with Grafana's `$__timeFilter` function?
3. Is pivoting the data required at all, can Grafana handle key value data without pivoting?

Comment: 465 milliseconds isn't lighting fast, but not that slow either. And you are processing 106233 records, this could be an hardware issue. Could you show us the results van EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) for this query?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/munnik/89a160a65454dd71f7e373459cf1a89b for the query plan

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- The key value approach can be an okay way to store things, though there are a few modifications I would make:

1. I'd definitely break out the name stuff into a separate table and filter those messages separately. That stuff is treated differently in your query and you should definitely be dealing with that separately on ingest rather than at query time.
2. You should probably think about indexing, probably one on (path, time), this will show up more as your data grows, but it looks like most of your time is spent scanning the table, right now it just has an index on time so it has to filter out all the other keys manually.  You also might think about whether you want to have a separate table to store your keys so you can store your paths as integers or something like that.
3. casting a varchar or text to numeric is probably a bad choice, storage costs are large, overhead is large etc. I would suggest that you use multiple columns with the actual type you want to store. Avoid numerics if you can, use floats for performance unless you truly need full precision for some reason. (Also, if you enable compression, the float/double compression is going to be much better than if the compression for numeric).

- To do your "pivoting" query, I would recommend using a `FILTER` clause on your aggregate see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES. That should at least eliminate those case statements. You can also then just use a `HAVING` clause in order to avoid another subselect if you'd prefer.

The query could look something like:

```
select
    time_bucket_gapfill('5 seconds', "time") as "time", -- create time buckets of 5 seconds
    "context",
    locf(last("value", "time") FILTER (WHERE "path" = 'navigation.position.longitude')) as "lon", -- last reported longitude in this bucket, if unknown in this bucket take the value of the previous bucket
    locf(last("value", "time") FILTER (WHERE "path" = 'navigation.position.latitude')) as "lat", -- last reported latitude in this bucket, if unknown in this bucket take the value of the previous bucket
    locf(last("value", "time") FILTER (WHERE "path" = 'navigation.speedOverGround')) as "sog", -- last reported speed over ground in this bucket, if unknown in this bucket take the value of the previous bucket
    locf(last("value", "time") FILTER (WHERE "path" = 'navigation.state'))) as "navstate" -- last reported navigation state in this bucket, if unknown in this bucket take the value of the previous bucket

from
    "key_value_data"
where
  $__timeFilter("time") and
    "path" in ('navigation.position.longitude', 'navigation.position.latitude', 'navigation.speedOverGround', 'navigation.state')
GROUP BY 
    1, 2
order by
    1, 2, 3
)
```

- I would avoid varchar in general, text is better in PG, varchar can add extra overhead (though that's mostly with the varchar(n) case, so probably not a huge problem here, I just prefer text). See: [https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This)

Comment: Thanks for the great reply! I will give these things a try and report back.